# Yellowish mushy stuff on cooked rice

Tags: rice

[image]

Found this yellowish mushy stuff on my freshly cooked plain rice, any idea what could it be?

Comment: what type of rice was it? did you use a rice cooker? what type of vessel? could it be something from the rice cooker / pot?

Comment: It is calrose rice cooked in rice cooker. Not likely from the rice cooker, it was cleaned.

Comment: looks aaalmost like a smushed lentil... any chances something like that might've been dropped in with the raw rice, somehow?

Comment: Well yeah the texture does feel like that. I don’t have lentil on my house. Perhaps it gets into the packaging during the manufacturing process.

Comment: We have no way to know what it is, it doesn't look like anything you normally find in rice, and we can't guess what went in your specific rice bag.